# What would be the impact of a CVE-2015-9251 vulnerability?

Tags: xss, cve, jquery

I've seen that in jQuery versions older than jQuery 3 there is the CVE-2015-9251 vulnerability which can result in cross-site scripting. Is this a limited vulnerability? What could be its possible effects? Should it be treated dangerous?

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a limited vulnerability?

It is limited in the sense that the vulnerability can only apply if your application is querying via `$.get` an untrusty/compromised website.

> What could be its possible effects?

As per the CVE, your application would be vulnerable to XSS and all of its implications.

> Should it be treated dangerous?

As much as any XSS execution in your application would be.